# System.SecurityString

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I have a function requiring a secure password as a parameter:

```
function Create-List
{
 param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Username,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
 [Security.SecureString]$password,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Url

)

 $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
 $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $password)

}
```

The intention is that instead of the password, Powershell will display *** when a user is entering

```
Create-List -password Passsword2144

Create-List -password ***********
```

but the password is still visible when the cmdlet is entered and after hitting enter, I get an error that Powershell cannot convert  Passsword2144 of type String to System.Security.SecureString. What am I doing wrong? Did I forget some reference?

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way, the globals are stored in my profile and then I can make all the functions operate in this way:

```
    #Global Variables
    $CAprod = "https://company-admin.sharepoint.com"
    $me = "myemail@company.com"
    $credential = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your Office 365 Administrative credentials" -UserName $me
    Connect-SPOService -Url $CAprod -Credential $credential

    function Foo-Bar{
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$SiteUrl

)
      $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
      $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)
    }
```

Comment: This is a valid workaround, but not an answer why SecureString parameter is not read as a SecureString. Do you know why [SecureString] is not working or how to create a parameter of SecureString type?

Comment: because a plain text password is not a secure string, it'd be best to use the get-credential and pass around a credential object instead of having a user supply their password in that fashion. If you are going to pass a string like that, then your function has to do the conversion of the string to a secure string.

Comment: so basically SecureString will never work as a parameter type?

Comment: It could I suppose, it just isn't that optimal in my opinion. It's best to use the get-credential commandlet and pass around a credential object or use the get-credential inside of your function. Supplying a plain text password that you then converto-securestring doesn't give me any warm fuzzies about your library.